# What is the ramp rate (up and down) of the Siemens SGT-800 gas turbine (62MW variant)?

Tags: turbines

I can't seem to find the ramp rate of the Siemens SGT-800 gas turbine in any of their brochures or data sheets. Looking specifically for the ramp rate of the Siemens 62MW SGT-800 gas turbine (in combined cycle).

Comment: Do they have an email address? Would they have a technical sales department?

Comment: The ramp rate of what?? Under what conditions?? These things are controlled by computers. The various rates will be constrained by dozens of dynamical factors.

Comment: surely you don't think people buy 62 MW turbines based off of brochures.

Comment: Tiger Guy - yes, most people don't buy a 20 million dollar gas turbine off a brochure; but one can at least compare the technical specs of similar gas turbines from different manufacturers.